# Importing model with transparent vertex colors not working

Tags: materials, eevee-render-engine, transparency, vertex-colors

I'm trying to import a 3d mesh I generated in another program to blender which uses vertex colors, but the transparent areas always look opaque. I've tried changing the material blend mode, viewport display color, and the alpha slider, but nothing has worked. Also, the mesh is darker in blender for some reason. Any idea on how I can get this to work?

What it's supposed to look like

[image]

What it looks like in blender

[image]

Comment: What do your shader nodes look like?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: to be more specific, when the mesh is not in blender, parts of it are transparent. when it is imported into blender, it is no longer transparent.